# Is there a way to increase the maximum number of Recent Projects in Spyder?

Tags: python, project, spyder

The number of recent projects that Spyder allows to see seems to be limited to 10. Is there a way to increase this number? 
I looked through Tools > Preferences, but could not find these settings. Also the search on this site, Spyder site, or in the internet did not provide an answer.
Is there a way to change the number through a file or a registry?

Comment: The feature is recently added to the new release of Spyder. Thanks @CarlosCordoba!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) There's no such option, but please open an issue about it [here](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues), so we don't forget to add it in the future.

Comment: There is this file in git repository: https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/blob/master/spyder/plugins/projects/plugin.py
I assume it is not possible to edit it in the spyder installation on my computer as it is probably already compiled, right?

Comment: BTW, I raised the issue as you suggested. Thanks! @AdamStrauss

Answer (score 0):

Something like that would be amazing. I am far from experienced enough of a coder to implement something like this.

And here is Spyder official [repository](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder). But I didn't find anything here. So till now it is not possible to do that.

Comment: I looked through the repository. It is indeed hard coded as you can see from file https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/blob/master/spyder/plugins/projects/plugin.py
The code reads
 `   def add_to_recent(self, project):
        """
        Add an entry to recent projetcs
        We only maintain the list of the 10 most recent projects
        """
        if project not in self.recent_projects:
            self.recent_projects.insert(0, project)
            self.recent_projects = self.recent_projects[:10]`
`code`